# Get links to streaming video from an iOS app

Tags: iphone, video-streaming, xcode, mac-app-store

There is this free app called GLWiz in the App Store, which basically allows you to watch satellite channels on your iPod. The good thing about this app is that you can have access to the HD links/channels as well for free.

**How can I get these MMS/ASX/RTMP streams (or whatever they are) on my computer** so I can watch them on a bigger screen (better than on an iPod)?

I checked GLWiz' website of course but they do not provide the HD stream – only SD (standard definition). Is there any way (through Xcode or something) to retrieve these links from the app? My iPod is already jailbroken so I just FTPed the application folder from its root from the iPod onto my computer and provided it [as a download here](http://aasingercom.ipage.com/files/glwiz.zip) (10 MB).

However, I have no experience with Xcode/XML/pList or whatever language it is written in to be able to understand how I would get these links.

Comment: I don't think you'll find much in the app itself. You'd rather want to sniff your network traffic to get the streaming URLs from there.

Comment: Nice thought, is there any program that will do the job? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your only chance is to actually inspect the network traffic your iPod sends/receives. [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org/) is the best known tool for this.

You just have to have your iPod and laptop (or any computer with a WiFi card) connect to the same (unprotected) WiFi network, then start [capturing packets](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup) from Wireshark in promiscuous mode (here's a [screencast on capturing](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/tip/Screencast-Catching-network-traffic-with-Wireshark)).

Ideally, you start capturing immediately before opening a video stream so you don't have to go through too many packets. Wireshark will offer you a wide range of inspection tools, for example filtering by the IP address of your iPod and the protocol used.

See also [this forum entry](http://stream-recorder.com/forum/showpost.php?p=11378&postcount=6) for a few screenshots and ideas.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, I am trying it out right now and I'll give a shout when its working :)

Comment: Nice! I must say: it works like a charm! Thanks, I just tried it out on the computer when opening up a stream, haven't yet tried it with the ipod. But one question: will this program also capture packets from other devices that are connected to the same router? Thanks

Comment: Yes, in promiscuous mode, you capture anything that is sent through the air. If the WiFi is unencrypted, you'll also be able to peek into all of those packets (unless the other devices are using secure connections, such as HTTPS).

Comment: Wow! Nice, never knew when the ssl encryptions came in with websites, now I know :) Btw, how do I put it into promiscuous mode? Thanks for your time

Comment: There should be an option in the *Capture* dialog when you open it. I don't have any Wireshark installation at hand, sorry, but it should be pretty obvious from the documentation – I'm sure you find something!

Comment: Yup I found it, and also found the links from my iPod. Thank you so ever much! Ur a pro!